# Code Igniter Update Engine

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am planning to develop a pretty awesome new web app that has a one time fee including free updates of 1.X updates (X being the update).

I don't want to get people to download a new version and install it manually as it can be a real pain for some people, also it's bad if there is an important bug that needs fixing and people don't update.

The app will be built with Code Igniter so I was looking for some kind of integrated system that allowed me to send out updates for the web app?

Comment: I know the question is really old but did you manage to find something?? The link on the comments is not working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None that I know of - basically CodeIgniter is just an MVC framework. You might consider looking into a generic update engine for web sites.

Comment: I know that but I was hoping for a class or something? :-)

Comment: Here is a thread on the CI forums about this topic: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/68281/P0/